# Groups and vectorspaces

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces

Let $(G, +)$ be a commutative Group with the neutral Element $e$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ be the field of remainders mod 2. The multiplication is declared as  $\star : \mathbb{Z}_2 \times G \rightarrow G : \overline{0} \star a := e, \overline{1} \star a := a$. What necessary and sufficient condition must $G$ satisfy, so that $G$ is a vectorspace over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: What have you tried? I guess a good question to ask yourself here is "what can happen that makes it not a vectorspace?"

Comment: I think only the 5 vectorspace axioms? But that does not work out.

Comment: A particular thing that holds for any vectorspace is that if $a$ is a non-zero scalar and $v$ is a non-zero vector, then $av\neq 0$. What happens if $v = w + w$ for some vector $w$?

Comment: So I need to show vector multiplication and vector addition works? Aaah, okay. I this all?

Comment: No, you need to find the conditions on the group $G$ that makes this work.

Comment: But what conditions? Commutative law, distributive law, etc.? Aren't those described in the 5 vectorspace axioms?

Comment: You are not given a vectorspace. You are given something and asked under what conditions it is in fact a vectorspace. This means you need to consider those axioms and see what you need to assume about $G$ in order for those to be fulfilled.

Comment: @EmilioJuarez "But that does not work out". Why? That is exactly what you should do. Each vector space axiom becomes a condition on group $G$, because the operation is known. Some of those axioms are fulfilled automatically because $G$ is an abelian group, so you can ignore them. All the rest will be meaningful conditions on $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These axioms are satisfied because $G$ is an Abelian group:

- Associativity of addition:  $u + (v + w) = (u + v) + w$
- Commutativity of addition:  $u + v = v + u$
- Identity element of addition:   $\exists e \in V: \forall v \in V: v + e = v$.
- Inverse elements of addition:   $\forall v \in V: \exists −v ∈ V: v + (−v) = e$

These still need to be checked to see if they impose any conditions on $G$:

- Identity element of scalar multiplication: $\bar{1}v = v$
- Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition: $(a + b)v = av + bv$
- Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector addition: $a(u + v) = au + av$
- Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication:   $a(bv) = (ab)v$

The first of these doesn't impose any restrictions on $G$. Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition implies $\bar{0}v = e$. This can be seen as follows:

$(\bar{1} + \bar{0})v = \bar{1}v + \bar{0}v \Rightarrow v = \bar{0}v + v \Rightarrow \bar{0}v = e$

This allows us to conclude that every element of $G$ needs to be it's own inverse:

$(\bar{1} + \bar{1})v = \bar{1}v + \bar{1} v \Rightarrow e = v + v \Rightarrow v = (-v)$

Given that we already know that $\bar{0}v = e$ and $\bar{1}v = v$, it is easy to check that distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to vector addition and compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication impose no new conditions on $G$.

Hence, the only requirement on $G$ is that each element is its own inverse: $\forall v \in G: v = (-v)$